# Internet speed fluctuating from slow to fast constantly

Tags: networking, 20.04

Kind of a noob. I've tried everything from turning off power management to changing/flushing my DNS, but the issue persists. From a quick speed test my Wifi tends to either be extremely slow or very fast (though mostly slow). What I've tried:

[Wifi signal keeps fluctuating and disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675518/wifi-signal-keeps-fluctuating-and-disconnecting)

[Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Download Speed very slow, Upload speed fairly good](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339254/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-download-speed-very-slow-upload-speed-fairly-good)

Comment: Create a live CD of either 20.04 LTS or 21.10. Boot to it, and press `Try Ubuntu`. See if you can reproduce your issue there (when you're done, shutdown the computer, unplug the PC, and it will boot back to your normal system)

Comment: I have tried that, and the issue just isn't there. The trial version had silky smooth connection, which just makes me more curious as to what could be the cause of my problem.

Comment: That does mean that it is a software issue (and something that you did, not a default). Have you made any networking-related changes?

Comment: Many of them, but from what I recall all were from help threads with people having the same problem. However, almost as if magically, the problem is resolved now (somehow). I pretty much just rebooted from using the flash drive and the same issue that plagued me for days is now gone apparently.

Comment: Check your MTU with `ip link`. It should be 1492 for WiFi. Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.